A complicated generalized perturbation ODE
Something I just cooked in my brain:
Let's look at the ODE:
$$(\epsilon/x'++x'/\epsilon)(x''/\epsilon^2+\epsilon^2/x'')\ldots (x^{(n)}/\epsilon^n +\epsilon^n /x^{(n)})=f(x,\epsilon)$$
$$x(0)=0,x'(0)=y_1(\epsilon),\ldots , x^{(n-1)}(0)=y_{n-1}(\epsilon)$$
Where the $y_i(\epsilon)$ never vanish for every value of $\epsilon$.
I assume one can have a Taylor series around $t=0$ for the function $f(x(t),\epsilon)$, and the general ansatz would be: $x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} a_n(t)\epsilon^n$, and I think one can also expand by a suitable Laurent sum for the $y_i$.
Eventaully I would like to find a formula for the generalized $a_n(t)$, may it be recursive (I will be surprised if there's a solution for this recursive equation without some special functions) with respect to the coefficients of the Taylor series coefficients of $f(x,\epsilon)$ and Laurent series' coeffiencients of the $y_i$'s.
Is it possible to implement in Mathematica?
If so, then how exactly?
Thanks in advance!
Eventually I would like to know if the series converges for when $\epsilon \to 1$, I think that it diverges for the general case; not sure how to prove it though...
